# Google Analytics, outgoing links by referer

Tags: google-analytics, referer

I want to know how many people (in percent) comming from a specific referer (like direct, paid search, organic search and so on) click on at least one outgoing link on my website. (If somebody clicks 10 outgoing links it should count as much as somebody who only clicks one link).
What i did was to create a custom event which is triggered every time a user clicks an outgoing lnik. This is working so far, but how can i filter the data in the way i explained before?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's easier if you use GAs own terminology - you will find direct/paid/organic etc. not under "referer" but under "medium". You then can create custom reports for your click event and apply a filter by medium.

Answer (score 1):

Use Unique Events.

http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2350415/How-to-Use-the-Google-Analytics-Event-Tracking-Report

> Unique Events: Events of the same type within the same session have
>   been removed from total events to de-duplicate them, this helps you
>   identify events which are triggered multiple times per session or if
>   an event is only important once then this is more important to you
>   than total events.

Alternatively, you could drop a key in localStorage (or a cookie) per link so you would only fire the event once per session/cookie.